# Edit video metadata on Ubuntu?

Tags: 22.04, video, metadata

I've been trying to edit metadata of some mp4 files, and been unable to do it on Ubuntu. I'm specifically looking to edit the 'rating' of the video. On windows, I can right click > properties > details and edit the rating just by clicking it (see image).

if possible, I'm happy to automate it using python too, so whatever works.

This is, for example, how I edit rating of a video file on windows:

[image]

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

to remove meta data you want to use exiftool like this:
`exiftool -all= video.mp4`

To install exiftool:
`sudo apt install libimage-exiftool-perl`

In VLC, I do see the metadata tab, but it doesn't seem to be listing anything.
with exiftool, to list the metadata:
exiftool video.mp4

Comment: Question was edit not remove.

Comment: Oops! well tag edits can be done with exiftool I omited that part of my snswer because I thought I was confussed. aw well, heres a link on how to do it. https://libre-software.net/linux/edit-metadata-exiftool/

Answer (score 0):

[**digiKam**](https://www.digikam.org/) is an easy and [feature rich](https://www.digikam.org/about/features/) GUI media files meta-data(*and more*) viewer and editor.

It is available from the official Ubuntu repositories and can be installed with:

```bash
sudo apt install digikam
```

Then, it can be run from the applications menu or simply by running it from the terminal like so:

```bash
$ digikam
```

[image]